# Is it possible to Use Hibernate Search 6 with WildFly 24?

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I want to use Hibernate Search 6 in my project which required Hibernate ORM 5.4 or higher. And I also use WildFly 24.0.1 which has out of the box Hibernate 5.3.
When I run WildFly server my .war in not deploying and i've got some errors.
I'll try to solve this by adding hibernate 5.4.32 to my pom.xml, but it's not working too and I've got another errors.

Is it real, or I can't do this and I need to wait the new version of WildFly with Hibernate 5.4 support?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Search 6 requires Hibernate ORM 5.4.4 or later, as documented [here](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/).

Whether it can work in WildFly or not is an open question; we haven't tried it, and work on the WildFly integration is planned for a [later version](https://hibernate.org/search/roadmap/).

All I can say is that at the moment, you will have to bundle Hibernate Search 6 with your application, as you would with any library that isn't included in WildFly, and you will have to upgrade the version of Hibernate ORM used in WildFly. The process to do so is documented [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/topical/html_single/wildfly/Wildfly.html), though I haven't checked whether this part of the documentation still works with the latest versions of WildFly.